# Best Postgresql index type to be used with not equal (<>) where condition

Tags: postgresql, indexing, where-clause, equality

I need to query two identical huge tables (more than milion records). Besides other conditions, there is also a not equal where condition on a columns pair of varchar type.

Is standard btree type index suitable or some other index type would be more suitable for not equal (<>) where condition?

Comment: Indexes are good to reduce many rows to a few rows based on a condition in your query. Unless you have a very unequal distribution of values, a "not equals" condition will most probably not be considered for an index lookup anyway.

Comment: This Question might be better placed on the sibling site, dba.StackExchange.com.

Answer (score 1):

Why not try it with different indexes and let Postgres tell you which was most effective with the [EXPLAIN](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/indexes-examine.html) command? Unless your data contains some sort of rare edge case which breaks indexing functionality, you can test it for real and see the actual results without having to guess.

Answer (score 0):

Heroku dev center guide seem to have good explanation on Postgres indexes. I personally use B-Tree indexes as they are transaction safe unlike Hash indexes. Please take a look.

"B-Tree is the default that you get when you do CREATE INDEX. Virtually all databases will have some B-tree indexes. B-trees attempt to remain balanced, with the amount of data in each branch of the tree being roughly the same. Therefore the number of levels that must be traversed to find rows is always in the same ballpark."

More details here : [Heroku Dev Center](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/postgresql-indexes)

Comment: Please include essential information *in your answer*, not in a link.

Comment: Note that since Postgres 10, hash indexes **are** crash safe.